# Local instance of wordpress edit plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've having an annoying issue with Wordpress.

First I have to say that I'm not very familiar with Wordpress, I’m using it because I agree to take the management of the website of my sport club.

Now let’s me explain the issue. The previous manager of the website found a plugin that he think will be nice for the website. 
But now that I’m managing, I want to make some change to this plugin (which is under GNU GPLv3 License so I have the right to do it).

So I install wamp on my computer, then wordpress and then I add the plugin to it in the purpose to test my changes. 
I was thinking that when editing the files under “…\wp-content\plugins...” it will take effect instantly but it’s not.

I try to restart wamp after making some changes but it does not solve my issue.

A bit later I found that in wordpress there is a plugin modification interface and when going in it I found that the changes that I made on the files where not taken. Is there a cache of the files or something?

So my question is the following: Is there a way to edit the files in the folders (I’m using Visual Studio Code) and that the changes are applied instantly to the “running” plugin in my local instance?

I hope I was able to be clear enough so you guys can understand me

Thanks in advance

Comment: The changes you make take effect without having to restart wamp. What may happen is that you are using a cache plugin which may need purging, and that web browsers also cache pages. For browser caching I ussually work with the browser inspect open and with the 'don't use cache' checkbox marked in the network tab. It isn't bullet proof but works most of the time.

Comment: If there's a caching plugin installed, try disabling it and check again.

Comment: I have already disable the cache and there is no caching plugin (it's a new installation of wordpress with only two plugins running, the one I try to edit and a plugin for table)